# Running Spring Boot on Amazon Lambda

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot application on Amazon Lambda.
I noticed that if the handler is called in quick succession - spring tries to reload itself, re-setup the datsources, reload beans etc

Is there anyway to tell Spring Boot not to reinitialize itself if the main method has already been called?

Thanks
Damien

Comment: I agreed with Andrew Campbell to using Spring Cloud Function for deployment on AWS Lambda. Here is a [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/run-code-with-spring-cloud-function-on-aws-lambda) that you can follow. If you need some example which integrate with other AWS services like S3, you can refer to the [sample](https://github.com/mengjiann/aws-lambda-s3) which I have written some time back.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, a Amazon Lambda is a stateless function, that is instantiated for every request.

If you call the Lambda many times, it is quite normal, that you see a Spring Boot initialization for every request.

If the requests come slowly, its possible that AWS is reusing the same Lambda again, so only one Spring initialization is done.

If the request come fast, or in parallel, AWS will launch more instances of Lambdas to scale dynamically. This explains what you are facing.

I think, using a whole Spring application as an AWS Lambda is not the right approach. A Lambda should be a stateless function, that can be instantiated quickly.

You might try to make your spring app as small as possible, to decrease load time and save resources, as explained in [this tutorial](https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2016/12/01/making-spring-boot-application-run-serverless-with-aws/).

Comment: Hi @Stefan. I agree on all those points. I thought about not using sping and looked at things like spark but I thought it had the potential to introduce bad coding practices. For the code I am writing - it is all queue based. Timing is important and is something I will be conscious of

Comment: I think this is a job for Spring Boot developers to reduce the overhead time to be usable in AWS Lambda, particularly in conjuction with API Gateway, to serve Spring MVC/Web apps. It's been done in the Python/Django world: http://www.zappa.io

Comment: If you like to see this please vote for https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10136

Answer (score 1):

I came across this searching for an answer and agree that Spring is typically way too slow to startup for Lambda.

I think Spring Cloud has solved this problem now with *Spring Cloud Function*:

> This project provides an adapter layer for a Spring Cloud Function
>   application onto AWS Lambda. You can write an app with a single @Bean
>   of type Function, Consumer or Supplier and it will be deployable in AWS

[https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-adapters/spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws)

**UPDATE:**
I've been working with Spring Cloud Function on AWS lambda a little more now. For most of my functions, the startup time is 4-5 seconds which isn't fantastic, but at the time of writing it is dirt cheap (free for the first millions requests/ $0.20 per million thereafter) and a strategy to prevent slow startups is to prevent the function(s) from ever shutting down (a.k.a. "Keeping them warm") by [setting up a CloudWatch rule](https://read.acloud.guru/how-to-keep-your-lambda-functions-warm-9d7e1aa6e2f0) to constantly kickoff the function and keep it alive.