# Any alternative frameworks like Spring but without using java reflections?

Tags: java, spring, reflection

It seems like **Java reflections** are having a huge performance impact on the **spring** application startup based on the size of the applications. So I am looking for an alternative framework like spring but without using java reflections. If none, any other **alternative** options in **pure Java** itself now or in future?

Comment: have you looked Dropwizard?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689282/spring-without-reflection ... there you'll also find some alternatives such as https://micronaut.io/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the Java-Framework [Micronaut](https://micronaut.io/) for your requirements.

Micronaut is designed using Ahead Of Time (AOT) Compilation. It avoids reflection during runtime and gives you a very fast startup time.

> The Micronaut framework features a dependency injection and aspect-oriented programming runtime that uses no reflection.

> Keeps your startup time and memory footprint low by doing the heavy lifting up-front